# use_frameworks! and podspec in the root of a library repo

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, magicalrecord

I have the following dependencies in my iOS project:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'CocoaLumberjack'

# other dependencies here    

pod 'MagicalRecord', :git => 'https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord.git', :branch => 'develop'
```

I use the latest version of CocoaPods at the moment (0.37.0). `pod install` gives no warnings or errors, but When I try to build, I get linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MagicalRecord+ErrorHandling.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+MagicalDataImport.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObject+MagicalRecord.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalObserving.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalRecord.o
      objc-class-ref in NSManagedObjectContext+MagicalSaves.o
      objc-class-ref in NSObject+MagicalDataImport.o
```

Apparently, `MagicalRecord` does not see `CocoaLumberjack`, which provides the symbol. Documentation says:

Sometimes you may want to use the bleeding edge version of a Pod, a specific revision or your own fork. If this is the case, you can specify that with your pod declaration.
**It is important to note, though, that this means that the version will have to satisfy any other dependencies on the Pod by other Pods.**

However, it is not explained how exactly these dependencies should be satisfied. Can anyone explain this? Everything worked fine until I added `use_frameworks!` to use pod written in Swift.

Comment: That's an obsolete issue for nowadays versions of CocoaPods (1.7.2+) and MagicalRecord (2.3.2+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a somewhat useable workaround for this problem by linking `CocoaLumberjack.framework` in the generated `Pods-MagicalRecord` target in `Pods.xcodeproj`. This will allow MagicalRecord to see DDLog, and so you should be able to compile. However, it's a pretty fragile solution, as you'll need to re-link the framework each time you regenerate the Pods project by running `pod install`.

[source](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/issues/988)